# How to initialize data in component according to the received props and don't lose reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-reactivity, vue-props

I have a problem with initialization data before component is created. **My actual question depends on that problem:** I'm losing reactivity in one of my data properties because I initialize it in lifecycle hook. But I don't know how to initialize an array from `data(){}` with a length which I receive from props. If I make it in lifecycle hook, then I'm losing reactivity, as I metioned before.
Here is some more details about my component:
In my Vue.js learning I'm trying to implement a stepper component. I decided to make it a little more dynamic and to be with a flexible size. So in my props of stepper component I receive an Object with such structure:

```
stepperData: {
        steps: 3,       //maybe later I'll add more options to stepperData, so I decided to implement it as an Object, not Array of content.
        content: [
          {
            header: "Stepper #1",
            text: "Hello World 1!"
          },
          {
            header: "Stepper #2",
            text: "Hello World 2!"
          },
          {
            header: "Stepper #3",
            text: "Hello World 3!"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Than in my stepper component I am using a `steps` field to determine a length of another array which hold data about marked or unmarked steps. Here is a code which I am using to initialize that array of marked steps:

```
methods: {
    initializeMarkedSteps() {
      this.markedSteps = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.dataStepper.steps; i++) {
        this.markedSteps[i] = false;
      }
    }
}, 
created: function() {
    this.initializeMarkedSteps();
  }
```

markedSteps is an empty array in `data(){}`
So, after that, I had an array of false values. In my template I have a `v-bind:class`

```
<div class="circle" v-bind:class="{markedCircle: markedSteps[s]}">
```

Thanks to it all of the steps are unmarked and they can became marked after user clicks "next" button.

```
<my-btn @click="nextStep">Next</my-btn>
```

my-btn is my wrapper component for simple button. 
Code in nextStep():

```
nextStep() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.dataStepper.steps; i++) {
    if (this.markedSteps[i] === false) {
      this.markedSteps[i] = true;
      console.log(this.markedSteps);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

BUT, when I click button, markedCircle class is not assigned as I expect despite the fact, that acual value of markedSteps[i] was changed to true after button was clicked.
I am very frustrated with this stuff with which I am so messed up. Any help will be appreciated. I have already checked docs on this theme and also  I've read "Reactivity in Depth" section but I didn't saw an answer.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems

1. In your examples you don't show how you initialize your `data()` but assuming from the code `this.markedSteps = [];` in `initializeMarkedSteps` I think you have no `markedSteps` in `data()`. That's problem number 1. [Properties in data are only reactive if they existed when the instance was created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) (add `markedSteps: []` into `data()`)
2. Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue [cannot detect changes to an array when you directly set an item with the index](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) - use `Vue.set(this.markedSteps, i, true)` instead

Comment: Thanks to your answer and comment of Michal Levý I changed my code and now it works! :) Thanks a lot! Very helpful! btw `markedSteps: []` was already in my data(), but I had to change setting data to `Vue.set(this.markedSteps, i, true)` to make it work. That was the key :)